# Basic Auth for Katalon

Tags: automated-tests, basic-authentication, katalon-studio

I’m writing automated tests for a web app on a server with basic authentication enabled.

I’ve tried passing the username and password in the URL and also using the web authentication function. I haven’t had any luck either way. Has anyone else attempted automating basic auth? For now, I’m logging in at beginning of the test manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [WebUI.authenticate()](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-authenticate.html#description) method:

```
WebUI.authenticate('http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth', 'admin', 'admin', 12)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that and was unsuccessful. Getting a similar experience to that of the other comments at the bottom of that page. I even tried the suggestions listed there. Chrome just opens up and quits. FireFox throws an error.